# Why is the minimum age for the Meta Quest platform 10 years old, but many Meta Quest only games are rated "Everyone"?

Tags: legal, meta-quest-2

Why is the minimum age for the Meta Quest platform 10 years old, but many Meta Quest only games are rated "Everyone"? Playstation has a similar situation. Sony says Playstation is for older children, but it has games for very young children.

If you can't use Meta Quest as a platform for children, because the minimum age is not met, then why are some games released for all age categories.

Does VR harm the health of children who are still developing? I'm not talking about games in general, but about the new VR worlds.

Comment: Is it actually rated "Everyone", or "Everyone 10+"?  Those are two different ratings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because those are ESRB ratings for games, which in the US, are merely just suggestions. Those are set in connection with the ESRB, [in one of two ways](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/ratings-process/):

1. If a game has a physical copy (in many cases, these often do not), they would have to submitted and reviewed by at least 3 rated, or
2. If the game is only digital, a rating is assigned via completing a form known as the [IARC](https://www.globalratings.com/). [Meta is a participating storefront](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/oculus-store-transitions-to-iarc-age-and-content-ratings/) in IARC, and [so are many others, including Sony.](https://www.globalratings.com/about.aspx#participants)

The 10 year old requirement comes from Meta's Terms of Service, not any of the games ratings, they're independent of each other. This actually used to be a 13 year old requirement since the beginning, but a [few months ago they started allowing 10-12 year olds to create parent-managed accounts](https://www.meta.com/blog/quest/meta-accounts-parent-managed-families/).

Comment: As I understand,the 13 year old requirement is more for the online account services, that if I'm not mistaken, means that the service is subject to [COPPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) - which is harder to get below than the ESRB ratings below E10+-T ratings, generally.